# MySQL datetime fields and daylight savings time -- how do I reference the "extra" hour?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, dst

I'm using the America/New York timezone.  In the Fall we "fall back" an hour -- effectively "gaining" one hour at 2am.  At the transition point the following happens:

it's 01:59:00 -04:00
then 1 minute later it becomes:
01:00:00 **-05:00**

So if you simply say "1:30am" it's ambiguous as to whether or not you're referring to the first time 1:30 rolls around or the second.  I'm trying to save scheduling data to a MySQL database and can't determine how to save the times properly.

Here's the problem:
"2009-11-01 00:30:00" is stored internally as 2009-11-01 00:30:00 -04:00
"2009-11-01 01:30:00" is stored internally as 2009-11-01 01:30:00 **-05:00**

This is fine and fairly expected.  But how do I save anything to 01:30:00 **-04:00**?  The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) does not show any support for specifying the offset and, accordingly, when I've tried specifying the offset it's been duly ignored.

The only solutions I've thought of involve setting the server to a timezone that doesn't use daylight savings time and doing the necessary transformations in my scripts (I'm using PHP for this).  But that doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't know enough about MySQL or PHP to form a coherent answer, but I'll bet it has something to do with conversion to and from UTC.

Comment: Internally they're all stored as a UTC, no?

Comment: I found http://web.ivy.net/~carton/rant/MySQL-timezones.txt an interesting read on the topic.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

MySQL's date types are, frankly, broken and cannot store *all* times correctly unless your system is set to a constant offset timezone, like UTC or GMT-5. (I'm using MySQL 5.0.45)

This is because **you can't store any time during the hour before Daylight Saving Time ends**. No matter how you input dates, every date function will treat these times as if they are during the hour after the switch.

My system's timezone is `America/New_York`. Let's try storing 1257051600 (Sun, 01 Nov 2009 06:00:00 +0100).

Here's using the proprietary INTERVAL syntax:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-11-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 3599 SECOND); # 1257051599
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-11-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 3600 SECOND); # 1257055200

SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-11-01 01:00:00' - INTERVAL 1 SECOND); # 1257051599
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-11-01 01:00:00' - INTERVAL 0 SECOND); # 1257055200
```

Even `FROM_UNIXTIME()` won't return the accurate time.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(1257051599)); # 1257051599
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(1257051600)); # 1257055200
```

Oddly enough, DATETIME *will* still store and return (in string form only!) times within the "lost" hour when DST starts (e.g. `2009-03-08 02:59:59`). But using these dates in any MySQL function is risky:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-03-08 01:59:59'); # 1236495599
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-03-08 02:00:00'); # 1236495600
# ...
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-03-08 02:59:59'); # 1236495600
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-03-08 03:00:00'); # 1236495600
```

The takeaway: If you need to store and retrieve *every* time in the year, you have a few undesirable options:

1. Set system timezone to GMT + some constant offset. E.g. UTC
2. Store dates as INTs (as Aaron discovered, TIMESTAMP isn't even reliable)
3. Pretend the DATETIME type has some constant offset timezone. E.g. If you're in `America/New_York`, convert your date to GMT-5 *outside of MySQL*, then store as a DATETIME (this turns out to be essential: see Aaron's answer). Then you must take great care using MySQL's date/time functions, because some assume your values are of the system timezone, others (esp. time arithmetic functions) are "timezone agnostic" (they may behave as if the times are UTC).

Aaron and I suspect that auto-generating TIMESTAMP columns are also broken. Both `2009-11-01 01:30 -0400` and `2009-11-01 01:30 -0500` will be stored as the ambiguous `2009-11-01 01:30`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this mrclay. You've outlined the situation here very accurately.

Comment: It appears option 3 is actually safer for time arithmetic because (it seems that) the functions were implemented before DST functionality was added.

E.g. TIMEDIFF('2009-11-01 02:30:00','2009-11-01 00:30:00') returns 2:00, which is correct for UTC, but in America/New_York the times are 3 hours apart.

Comment: -1: You've made the mistake that MySQL date/time functions operate on a DATETIME type, which is timezone-agnostic.  The argument you're passing to UNIX_TIMSTAMP is therefore `select '2009-11-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 3600 SECOND;` which is `'2009-11-01 01:00:00'`.  UNIX_TIMESTAMP then simply attempts to covert this to UTC in the context of the session timezone - it doesn't attempt to perform the addition in the context of that timezone's DST rules.

Comment: @kbro OK, but the problem remains. If the session tz is `America/New_York`, I see no way to store 1257051600. Do you?

Answer (score 93):

I've got it figured out for my purposes.  I'll summarize what I learned (sorry, these notes are verbose; they're as much for my future referral as anything else).

Contrary to what I said in one of my previous comments, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP fields **do** behave differently.  TIMESTAMP fields (as the docs indicate) take whatever you send them in "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" format and convert it from your current timezone to UTC time.  The reverse happens transparently whenever you retrieve the data.  DATETIME fields do not make this conversion.  They take whatever you send them and just store it directly.

**Neither the DATETIME nor the TIMESTAMP field types can accurately store data in a timezone that observes DST**.  If you store "2009-11-01 01:30:00" the fields have no way to distinguish which version of 1:30am you wanted -- the -04:00 or -05:00 version.

Ok, so we must store our data in a non DST timezone (such as UTC).  TIMESTAMP fields are unable to handle this data accurately for reasons I'll explain: if your system is set to a DST timezone then what you put into TIMESTAMP may not be what you get back out.  Even if you send it data that you've already converted to UTC, it will still assume the data's in your local timezone and do yet another conversion to UTC.  This TIMESTAMP-enforced local-to-UTC-back-to-local roundtrip is lossy when your local timezone observes DST (since "2009-11-01 01:30:00" maps to 2 different possible times).

With DATETIME you can store your data in any timezone you want and be confident that you'll get back whatever you send it (you don't get forced into the lossy roundtrip conversions that TIMESTAMP fields foist on you).  So the solution is to use a DATETIME field and **before saving to the field** convert from your system time zone into whatever non-DST zone you want to save it in (I think UTC is probably the best option).  This allows you to build the conversion logic into your scripting language so that you can explicitly save the UTC equivalent of "2009-11-01 01:30:00 -04:00" or ""2009-11-01 01:30:00 -05:00".

Another important thing to note is that MySQL's date/time math functions don't work properly around DST boundaries if you store your dates in a DST TZ.  So all the more reason to save in UTC.

In a nutshell I now do this:

#### When retrieving the data from the database:

Explicitly interpret the data from the database as UTC outside of MySQL in order to get an accurate Unix timestamp. I use PHP's strtotime() function or its DateTime class for this.  It can not be reliably done inside of MySQL using MySQL's CONVERT_TZ() or UNIX_TIMESTAMP() functions because CONVERT_TZ will only output a 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' value which suffers from ambiguity problems, and UNIX_TIMESTAMP() assumes its input is in the system timezone, not the timezone the data was ACTUALLY stored in (UTC).

#### When storing the data to the database:

Convert your date to the precise UTC time that you desire outside of MySQL.  For example: with PHP's DateTime class you can specify "2009-11-01 1:30:00 EST" distinctly from "2009-11-01 1:30:00 EDT", then convert it to UTC and save the correct UTC time to your DATETIME field.

Phew.  Thanks so much for everyone's input and help.  Hopefully this saves someone else some headaches down the road.

BTW, I am seeing this on MySQL 5.0.22 and 5.0.27

Answer (score 14):

I think micahwittman's [link](http://web.ivy.net/~carton/rant/MySQL-timezones.txt) has the best practical solution to these MySQL limitations: Set the session timezone to UTC when you connect:

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+0:00'
```

Then you just send it Unix timestamps and everything should be fine.

Comment: This advice works fine. Problem is solved after I init all connections in my pool with the given statement.

Comment: The link no longer works.  I found it on Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20170314162825/web.ivy.net/~carton/rant/MySQL-timezones.txt

Answer (score 6):

> But how do I save anything to 01:30:00
>   -04:00?

You can convert to UTC like:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2009-11-29 01:30:00','-04:00','+00:00');
```

---

Even better, save the dates as a [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) field.  That's always stored in UTC, and UTC doesn't know about summer/winter time.

You can convert from UTC to localtime using [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'+00:00','SYSTEM');
```

Where '+00:00' is UTC, the from timezone , and 'SYSTEM' is the local timezone of the OS where MySQL runs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As best I can tell, despite what the docs say, TIMESTAMP and Datetime fields are behaving identically: they store their data in UTC, but they expect their input to be in local time and they automatically convert it into UTC -- if I convert to UTC first the database has no idea I did that and it adds 4 (or 5, depending on whether or not we're DST) more hours to the time.  So the problem remains: how do I specify 2009-11-01 01:30:00 -04:00 as input?

Comment: Well, I've discovered that the source of most of my confusion is the fact that the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function always interprets its date parameter relative to the current time zone whether or not you're pulling the data from a TIMESTAMP or a DATETIME field.  This makes sense now that I think about it.  I'll update more later.

Answer (score 5):

Mysql inherently solves this problem using time_zone_name table from mysql db.
Use CONVERT_TZ while CRUD to update the datetime without worrying about daylight savings time.

```
SELECT
  CONVERT_TZ('2019-04-01 00:00:00','Europe/London','UTC') AS time1,
  CONVERT_TZ('2019-03-01 00:00:00','Europe/London','UTC') AS time2;
```

Answer (score 4):

This thread made me freak since we use `TIMESTAMP` columns with `On UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (ie: `recordTimestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) to track changed records and ETL to a datawarehouse.

In case someone wonder, in this case, `TIMESTAMP` behave correctly and you can differentiate between the two similar dates by converting the `TIMESTAMP` to unix timestamp:

```
select TestFact.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(recordTimestamp) from TestFact;

id  recordTimestamp         UNIX_TIMESTAMP(recordTimestamp)
1   2012-11-04 01:00:10.0   1352005210
2   2012-11-04 01:00:10.0   1352008810
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on logging counts of visits of pages and displaying the counts in graph (using Flot jQuery plugin). I filled the table with test data and everything looked fine, but I noticed that at the end of the graph the points were one day off according to labels on x-axis. After examination I noticed that the view count for day 2015-10-25 was retrieved twice from the database and passed to Flot, so every day after this date was moved by one day to right.
After looking for a bug in my code for a while I realized that this date is when the DST takes place. Then I came to this SO page...
...but the suggested solutions was an overkill for what I needed or they had other disadvantages. **I am not very worried about not being able to distinguish between ambiguous timestamps.** I just need to count and display records per days.

First, I retrieve the date range:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(MIN(created_timestamp)) AS min_date, 
    DATE(MAX(created_timestamp)) AS max_date 
FROM page_display_log
WHERE item_id = :item_id
```

Then, in a for loop, starting with `min_date`, ending with `max_date`, by step of one day (`60*60*24`), I'm retrieving the counts:

```
for( $day = $min_date_timestamp; $day <= $max_date_timestamp; $day += 60 * 60 * 24 ) {
    $query = "
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_per_day
        FROM page_display_log
        WHERE 
            item_id = :item_id AND
            ( 
                created_timestamp BETWEEN 
                '" . date( "Y-m-d 00:00:00", $day ) . "' AND
                '" . date( "Y-m-d 23:59:59", $day ) . "'
            )
    ";
    //execute query and do stuff with the result
}
```

My **final and quick solution** to **my** problem was this:

```
$min_date_timestamp += 60 * 60 * 2; // To avoid DST problems
for( $day = $min_date_timestamp; $day <= $max_da.....
```

So I am **not staring the loop in the beginning of the day, but two hours later**. The day is still the same, and I am still retrieving correct counts, since I explicitly ask the database for records between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 of the day, regardless of the actual time of the timestamp. And when the time jumps by one hour, I am still in the correct day.

*Note: I know this is 5 year old thread, and I know this is not an answer to OPs question, but it might help people like me who encountered this page looking for solution to the problem I described.*

Comment: Probably not relevant to the actual question, but this is horribly inefficient, and no-one should copy it!  Instead, issue a single query such as:

Comment: `"SELECT CAST(created_timestamp AS date) day,COUNT(*) WHERE item_id=:item_id AND (created_timestamp BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", $min_date_timestamp)."' AND '".date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", $max_date_timestamp)."') GROUP BY day ORDER BY day";`