# DATETIME /  timezone?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using this to store DATETIME in mysql

**validation.php**

```
//more code
$date = new DateTime("2012-01-01 23:59:59", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
$dt = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//and I am posting into my DATETIME field:

Insert...Value($dt)
```

1.. I get no errors but the date/time posted is 0000-00-00 00-00-00

What am I doing wrong?

2.. Is there a way to store date formatted as DD-MM-YYYY?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573660/php-mysql-timestamp-and-timezones

Comment: @DainisAbols Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it... Correct syntax is:

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')); 
$dt = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set timezone with PHP before store to database

```
$date = new DateTime("2012-07-05 16:43:21", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
```

Comment: So if I use `$date = new DateTime("2012-07-05 16:43:21", new DateTimeZone('UTC+2'));` and then post $dt the time stored will be in UTC+2 format? This "2012-07-05 16:43:21" can be anything?

Comment: yes, you are right. But you can not write "UTC+2" you have get your timezone name like "Europe/Paris"

Comment: I add the line you told me but now I get error **Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string**

Comment: it works for me very simply $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

Answer (score 0):

You have to post

```
$var_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP')
```

not directly $date