# MySQL timestamp - correct days

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have events stored in the MySQL datebase with start date and time stored in column 'startTimeStamp' in UNIX format.

When I try to get events for particular date using simple query

SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(`startTimeStamp`, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2013-08-20'

everything works fine when date and time under timestamp is bigger then 2AM (i.e. 2013-08-20 03:00:00) but when it's earlier it's not displaying in same day.

Quick example: I have two events - same date but different time

> 1. 2013-08-20 03:00:00 (1376960400)
> 2. 2013-08-20 00:00:00 (1376949600)

I will get the first one when I run query mentioned before, but not the second one. To get the second one I have to query for events from day earlier (2013-08-19)

Do you have any idea why? Maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: may be you should set default timezone for that.

Answer (score 0):

See what you timezone is:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

And then set it correctly:

```
SET time_zone = timezonename;
```

EDIT:
This might help:[MySQL datetime fields and daylight savings time -- how do I reference the "extra" hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646171/mysql-datetime-fields-and-daylight-savings-time-how-do-i-reference-the-extra)

Comment: @@global.time_zone - SYSTEM
@@session.time_zone - SYSTEM

I think this is ok? Isn't it?

Comment: @Real299 Yeah it takes you computer timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have chosen a place where the [daylight saving time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) applies to. The time shifting in this case is mostly done between 2AM and 3AM in the morning, which may result in the different days.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically because the Unix timestamp meaning. It's just the number of seconds from 1-1-1970, so technically the 1376949600 value could still be the previous day, depends on your timezone.

In my case:

```
echo date("d-m-Y h:i", 1376949600);
// output: 19-08-2013 11:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$d="1376960400";
echo date("Y-m-d",$d);
```

you can use which format you want from [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)