# Displaying mysql datetime column in custom timezone

Tags: mysql

I need to display a datetime column in US Eastern time plus 7 hours (GMT+2 or GMT+3 depending on DST). DST starts 2nd Sunday of March at 9am (2am + 7) and ends 1st Sunday of Nov at 9am.

How can I create a custom timezone in MySQL?

Assuming I can setup the custom timezone 'nyPlus7' I wanted to do this query:

```
-- Count number of people born by month
select
  date_format(convert_tz(birth_day, 'system', 'nyPlus7'), '%Y-%m') as birth_month,
  count(id) as total
from person
group by birth_month
```

Sample output:

```
birth_month total
1974-01     23
1974-02     6
1974-03     8
```

Comment: This gets pretty complicated depending on your sensitivity, though using a TIMESTAMP and set time_zone may be enough for your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646171/mysql-datetime-fields-and-daylight-savings-time-how-do-i-reference-the-extra

Comment: I couldn't find a way to simply add custom timezone to mysql so I've reverted to a workaround where I store the converted & formatted month string as a database column.