# Change UTC time to IST (Asia/Kolkata) time in PHP

Tags: php

```
while($chat = $result->fetch_object()){

        // Returning the GMT (UTC) time of the chat creation:

        $chat->time = array(
            'hours'     => date('H',strtotime($chat->ts)),
            'minutes'   => date('i',strtotime($chat->ts))
        );
```

I'm using this code to display time alongside chat message. How can I change this code to display output time in IST timezone? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend you to store that values and work with a specific timezone in your DB. Instead I strongly advise you to use the conversions just to show to [your users the right time where they are, Stack already discussed about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525617/how-to-detect-users-timezone). I know that you already solved your problem, I just want to give my two cents about that, if someone come to your question and decides use date_default_timezone_set or setting in INI.

Anyways, [UTC seems to be a very stable candidate with good timezone translation support.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646420/why-should-i-use-utc)

Answer (score 3):

You've several ways to achieve this, a simple one is using [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before `date`, i.e.:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```