# Mysql - seconds difference unexpected result

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I need to calculated difference in seconds between 2 dates. I cannot use TIMEDIFF because of its [limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html).

When I use:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-28 08:21:15') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-27 08:21:15');
```

it returns expected 86400 seconds (what gives 24 hours) but when I use:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-29 08:21:15') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-27 08:21:15');
```

it seems it doesn't give 86400*2 but 169200 instead what gives 47 hours.

The question is - why is that? Is it a bug or feature? Is there any other reasonable way to calculate time difference not worrying about time limitations?

Comment: It is not clear to me from your link about what limitations you are talking about. Also `select TIMEDIFF('2015-03-29 08:21:15', '2015-03-27 08:21:15')` gives `48:00:00`. And additionally the idea that you manually try to invent a time difference algorithm sounds like a terrible idea bout YMMV.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Those dates are only sample. I have much longer periods.

Comment: Surprisingly, on my machine it outputs 172800, which equals to 86400*2. OS: Windows XP, MySQL 5.5.25a.

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP is timezone specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways in which this problem can be tackled:

**With [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)**:

Use `SET SESSION time_zone = '+0:00'` before carrying out date operations.

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+0:00';
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-29 08:21:15') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-27 08:21:15');
```

This returns `172800`, i.e. a proper time difference of `48 hours`. 
[Demo](http://rextester.com/RBU19181).

---

**With [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)**:

If you don't wish to use `SET SESSION time_zone`, you could try `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-29 08:21:15') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-03-27 08:21:15');
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2015-03-27 08:21:15', '2015-03-29 08:21:15');
```

The first computation results in `169200` (i.e. `47 hours`) and the second shows `172800` (i.e. `48 hours`). 
Remember though that the smaller timestamp should be used first in `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`, or you'd get a negative result. Alternatively, you could wrap `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` under [`ABS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) as so:

```
SELECT ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2015-03-29 08:21:15', '2015-03-27 08:21:15'));
```

[Rextester link.](http://rextester.com/MJFY10163)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, just curious if `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` was of any help?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I haven't answered before but didn't have time to look. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` does the job.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinNabiałek! Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that in 2015 there was Daylight changing at 29 March, it could be the reason 
[Daylight saving 2015](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2015)

Comment: This answer, if read in conjunction with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646171/2298301) would make sense. If we were to look at individual values, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` conversion over `2015-03-28 08:21:15` returns `1427527275` and `2015-03-29 08:21:15` returns `1427610075`. Difference of `82800`, translating into `23` hours.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, just to _test_ one of the answers given in the linked question above: http://rextester.com/RBU19181. Of course, it's based on an assumption that no consideration is required for Daylight Savings.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's really Daylight saving problem. But how would it be possible to calculate it without it? @DhruvSaxena any idea how to calculate it without getting into limit of `838:59:59` of `TIMEDIFF`?