# unable to insert timestamp "2018-03-25 03:58:31" into mysql

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp

As the title suggests, i'm unable to insert this timestamp specificly into the database. The date is valid, why doesn't it insert? The error I'm getting is: 
`Warning: #1299 Invalid TIMESTAMP value in column`

Comment: And your code is where?

Comment: it's just an sql statement.  have 100's of rows and other timestamp values insert, but this one specificly does not. The code is valid, the timestamp is not and I'm trying to find out why it is not valid.

Comment: What data type is your column?

Comment: it's `timestamp`

Comment: Not sure how can anyone help you without actually seeing the code.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eedc84/1 It should work

Comment: **this is not the codes fault**, byt mysql's, because the timestamp `2018-03-25 04:00:00` Does insert fine.

Comment: Daylight saving time 2018 in Lithuania began at 03:00 on Sunday, 25 March

Comment: Correct, I'm in Lithuania, and my timestamp is set to this timezone.

Comment: How about you reproduce your error on your system with the code I wrote in the SQLFiddle of my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the Daylight Savings Time (25th march this year), maybe this can help  [MySQL datetime fields and daylight savings time -- how do I reference the "extra" hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646171/mysql-datetime-fields-and-daylight-savings-time-how-do-i-reference-the-extra)