# Configure mySQL to inherit the operating system's timezone

Tags: mysql, apache, server, centos, admin

Our local clocks just went forward for daylight saving's time, and as usual our database server is an hour off again. Is it possible to configure `my.cnf` to simply inherit the timezone offset from Cent OS or are we destined to have to change it manually every six months?

Comment: You should find the answer on this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650910/11291413](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650910/11291413)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to add a hash before `default-time-zone` from `/etc/my.cnf` to disable it, then restart MySQL.

[As the manual describes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-time-zone), MySQL will default to [system_time_zone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_system_time_zone) if the default is not explicitly set.

> If this option is not given, the default time zone is the same as the system time zone (given by the value of the system_time_zone system variable.

Answer (score 0):

My answer got converted to comment for some reason because it was short.

Your database is most likely set to the same timezone as the server. The issue is the following:

> Neither the DATETIME nor the TIMESTAMP field types can accurately
>   store data in a timezone that observes DST. If you store "2009-11-01
>   01:30:00" the fields have no way to distinguish which version of
>   1:30am you wanted -- the -04:00 or -05:00 version.

For a detailed answer take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650910/11291413