# WHEN I am inserting the value "2024-03-10 02:06:35" in column 'timestamp' of type 'timestamp' from pyspark it is showing data truncation error

Tags: python, sql, mysql, pyspark, apache-kafka

I know that timestamptype can only accommodate value from 1970 to 2035. but my value is 2024. I am not able to find a solution for the same. When I am manually setting the datatype to 'datetime' it is working fine. I don't want to manually set the datatype for every spark job I run.

i tried changing the data type. i tried converting the columns to string and then to time stamp but this 2024-03-10 02:****** series always seems to give error. Also the values previous to it and next are getting stored fine.

Comment: Probably the Unix notion of a timestamp is expected as the input: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Definition

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VPfB If you're trying to say that it wants the numeric value, that's not how the MySQL TIMESTAMP datatype works. It's similar to DATETIME, it expects a date and time string.

Comment: The problem with that time is that it doesn't exist in most of the US. 3/10 is when we changed to Daylight Saving Time, so the clock jumped from 01:59:59 to 03:00:00.

Comment: Perhaps this question and its answers can help you?https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646171/3604523